# In app purchases' funds aren't showing up

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase

I am using the uwp store sample : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Store
and when I make an in app purchase, I do not see the funds showing up in my developer dashboard. I have ascociated the package with the store, and published it. I am using the windows.services.store, and even once the iap has been fufilled, after several days, the funds arent showing upp. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the records of your successful purchases shown in [add-on acquisitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/add-on-acquisitions-report)?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT Yes, they show up in the add-on aquisitions report, but I havent received any funds from them.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT  However, When I purchase one of my own apps, the funds come through, just not when I purchase the In-app purchase.

Comment: You could go [there](http://aka.ms/storesupport) to consult the team who can track your payment process to ask for help directly.